# How to go to specific section using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my site: http://2helix.com.au/v-04/ It's simple, built with HTML.

Now you can right side navbar. When you click on any link it will show you content. By default all content is hidden.

Now I want to point that section when I click on the link. For example: If I click on **social** link it's should go to **social content** section.

I know, If I use this It's should work:

```
<li><a class="showSingle social" target="1" href="social">SOCIAL</a></li>
<div id="social"></div>
```

If I do this then page is open on new window.

How can I smoothly go to that section without new window?

Thanks.

**Here is my code:**

```
<ul class="nav">                            
    <li><a href="mySocial" class="showSingle social" target="1">SOCIAL</a></li>
    <li><a class="showSingle" target="2">DIGITAL</a></li>
    <li><a class="showSingle" target="3">DESIGN</a></li>
    <li><a class="showSingle" target="4">DEVELOPMENT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>               

<div class="container content"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div id="div1 mySocial" class="targetDiv socialContent">
                <h3 class="left"><span>1</span></h3>
                <div class="textContent">
                    <h1><strong>SOCIAL</strong></h1>
                    <p>As Social Media becomes more intrinsic in our daily life’s, </p> 
                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="div2" class="targetDiv">
                <h3 class="left"><span>2</span></h3>
                <div class=" textContent">
                    <h1><strong>DIGITAL</strong></h1>
                    <p>Whethere it's eCommerce, web sites, EDM templates</p>    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="div3" class="targetDiv">
                <h3 class="left"><span>3</span></h3>                
                <div class="textContent">                   
                    <h1><strong>DESIGN</strong></h1>
                    <p>Requiremtns for design in social </p>    
                </div>              
            </div>

            <div id="div4" class="targetDiv">
                <h3 class="left"><span>4</span></h3>                
                <div class="textContent">
                    <h1><strong>DEVELOPMENT</strong></h1>
                    <p>Success in Social is standing out</strong></p>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

// jQuery code...
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(function(){      
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
            jQuery('.content').show();
            jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
            jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question. What does your *"social"* content section look like? How are content sections shown / hidden?

Comment: Have you tried `href="#social"` instead of `href="social"`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include all of the *relevant* code [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows us what you have done, so we have enough information to help.

Comment: @RohitVerma let me check with that.

Comment: @RohitVerma it's not working.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I m doing it

Comment: Okay. I have updated my code.

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed So you just want to scroll to that section to show it on the face ?

Comment: @RohitVerma Yes, scroll down to that corresponding section but note by default all content is hidden.

Comment: Because you are hiding all the rest of the content, there is nothing to scroll down to! See my answer below that demonstrates that. If my answer doesn't address your issue, what *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add also this code on click.

```
jQuery('html').animate({
scrollTop: jQuery(".content").offset().top
});
```

Comment: got it. Working fine.

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed this might achieve the scroll, but you still need to address the many errors in your code - you are using a lot of invalid HTML that will cause other issues.

Answer (score 2):

You've a huge number of problems with your basic HTML code that you need to fix before you even look at adding jQuery

1. You cannot give an element 2 ids. `<div id="div1 mySocial" class="targetDiv socialContent">` is not valid. You will need to create a separate element for your anchor e.g. `<a id="mySocial"></a>`
2. To link to an anchor you need to use `#` in the href, e.g. `<a href="#mySocial" class="social" >`
3. You cannot use `target` like that. There are [specific values that are allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) and numbers are not any of them. Instead you could use the `data-target`

Now to what you are trying to do with jQuery...

 You are hiding all content except for the one you click on, so there is no scrolling required... see the working example below. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(function(){      
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
            jQuery('.content').show();
            jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
            jQuery('#div'+$(this).data('target')).show();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">                            
    <li><a href="#mySocial" class="social showSingle" data-target="1">SOCIAL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#digital" class="showSingle" data-target="2">DIGITAL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#design" class="showSingle" data-target="3">DESIGN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#development" class="showSingle" data-target="4">DEVELOPMENT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>               

<div class="container content"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a id="mySocial"></a>
            <div id="div1" class="targetDiv socialContent">
                <h3 class="left"><span>1</span></h3>
                <div class="textContent">
                    <h1><strong>SOCIAL</strong></h1>
                    <p>As Social Media becomes more intrinsic in our daily life’s, </p> 
                </div>
            </div>


            <a id="digital"></a>
            <div id="div2" class="targetDiv">
                <h3 class="left"><span>2</span></h3>
                <div class=" textContent">
                    <h1><strong>DIGITAL</strong></h1>
                    <p>Whethere it's eCommerce, web sites, EDM templates</p>    
                </div>
            </div>

            <a id="design"></a>
            <div id="div3" class="targetDiv">
                <h3 class="left"><span>3</span></h3>                
                <div class="textContent">                   
                    <h1><strong>DESIGN</strong></h1>
                    <p>Requiremtns for design in social </p>    
                </div>              
            </div>

            <a id="development"></a>
            <div id="div4" class="targetDiv">
                <h3 class="left"><span>4</span></h3>                
                <div class="textContent">
                    <h1><strong>DEVELOPMENT</strong></h1>
                    <p>Success in Social is standing out</p>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your jquery code like This:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function() {
      jQuery('.content').show();
      jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
      jQuery('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).offset().top
      }, 500);
      return false;
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace

```
target = "1"
```

with

```
data-target = "#social"
```

then the link will jump down to a div with the id = "social"

```
<li><a class="showSingle social" data-target="social" href="social">SOCIAL</a></li>
<div id="social"></div>
```